# Why can't I force users to login to download a zip file from my website?

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a directory which contains a zip file and a pptx (PowerPoint) file. In the directory **is this .htaccess (regex?) code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?mydomain.me.uk/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink.(pptx|ppt|pdf|zip|7z|rar|xls|xlsx|doc|docx) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*.(pptx|ppt|pdf)$ http://mydomain.me.uk/  [NC]
```

When a user puts in the direct URL for pptx file, they are correctly served a 404 unless they are logged in. **For zip and 7z (7zip) files they can still download those files without being logged in**, even though those file extensions are correctly listed (to block) in my .htaccess code.

Why doesn't this code work for archived files?

Answer (score 1):

This might be completely stupid, but maybe it has something to do with HTTP compression. Try disabling mod_deflate, restart apache, and see if it works then. This is just a hunch though and might have nothing to do with it.

Comment: That sounds highly likely to be it. Rather than disable the compression - is there a way to make compression compatible with what I'm trying to do? I think that if I could amend my code to be compression friendly that would do wonders

Comment: I believe you wildly overestimate my expertise, I am just spitballing here. Have you tried the solution and confirmed that it works? If yes, this might be a bug worth reporting. As far as I am concerned configuring apache is always a huge pain in the butt.

Comment: Well I checked for caching plugins on the site, there are none. I checked the main .htaccess there's no usage of deflate!

Comment: Have you checked httpd.conf or apache2.conf respectively? If you have a2dismod installed, you can try

   `sudo a2dismod deflate`

to disable the module

Comment: What I did was edit my .htaccess file in that one folder like this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?creativejames.me.uk/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink.(pptx|ppt|pdf|zip|7z|rar|xls|xlsx|doc|docx) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*.(pptx|ppt|pdf)$ http://creativejames.me.uk/  [NC]

That shoudl be turning off deflate for that one folder but it still won't work...

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm here to answer my own question!

There were **two things wrong with my original code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?mydomain.me.uk/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink.(pptx|ppt|pdf|zip|7z|rar|xls|xlsx|doc|docx) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*.(pptx|ppt|pdf)$ http://mydomain.me.uk/  [NC]
```

The final line neglected to mention all of the file formats I wanted to suppress although this was all referenced correctly on line 3 (my code was incomplete!)

In addition to this as afdggfh said: I needed to suppress gzip compression in the specified folder.

As such I came up with **much more robust code instead:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?mydomain.me.uk/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink.(pptx|ppt|pdf|zip|7z|rar|xls|xlsx|doc|docx) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*.(pptx|ppt|pdf|zip|7z|rar|xls|xlsx|doc|docx)$ http://mydomain.me.uk/  [NC]
```

Above is the code that works!